# Return the other model's field as a response to POST request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my `models.py` there are two models:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    genre_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    information = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

They are serialized:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'genre')


class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('name', 'information')
```

and `ViewSets` are created for each:

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer


class GenreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GenreSerializer
```

What I'd like to do is:

1. Sending a `POST` request to `books/` endpoint. Sent data has to contain existing genre ID, it won't be saved to the database otherwise (it's done by default already).
2. Receiving `information` from the `Genre` model as a response.

Let me give a short example:

1. I'm sending this JSON:

   `{
       "title": "Hercules Poirot",
       "author": "Agatha Christie",
       "genre": 1
   }`
2. Instead of repeated request from above I receive something like this:

   `{ "genre": "crime story" }`

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a custom `create` method within your `BookViewSet` to override the return statement.

You can take exemple on the default `create` method which is implemented within `CreateModelMixin` (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L12)

Answer (score 0):

You could tell how the nested field will work. Like this:

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('name', 'information')


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre = GenreSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'genre')
```